# What function can be used to calculate cube root in pine-script, TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api, secure-trading

What function can be used to calculate cube root in pine-script, TradingView?

There is only a function to calculate square root and for power raised to.

Answer (score 0):

use pow function with 1/3.. like cube root of X is also X^(1/3)

```
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_pow
```